# Spring Form Validation validates database insert?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to use Spring Validation with Annotations to validate my form data. 
So i have the following object for example:

```
@Entity
@ComponentScan
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String type;

    ...
}
```

As you can see here i used `@NotEmpty` on the `type` String. I want to use this only to validate my form. It should not be validating for database inserts.

So when i do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String categoryPOST(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @Valid Category category, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }

    return "redirect:/results";
}
```

It is working as i want it to work. But when i have to create a dummy object:

```
Category category = new Category();
```

and i perform a save on that empty object:

```
this.category_repository.save(category);
```

I get the error (only important part of it):

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [my.project.jpa.entity.Category] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='darf nicht leer sein', propertyPath=type, rootBeanClass=class my.project.jpa.entity.Category, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
```

And that is not what i want. I want to use the annotation for form validation but i do not want the validation to get performed on database operations.

is that somehow possible?

**Additional information**

I had the same result using:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

Annotation.

Comment: BTW, `@ComponentScan` annotation on the entity looks strange. Are you sure that you need it?

Comment: No, not sure. completely new to spring.

Comment: Most likely you can remove it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-autodetection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The first option is to use different classes for a form object (DTO) and entity.

The second option is to configure Hibernate and disable validation before saving. Because this question already answered couple of times, I will provide links to them:

- [How do you turn off Hibernate bean validation with JPA 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488702/how-do-you-turn-off-hibernate-bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0)
- [Disabling Hibernate Validation on save/update with Hibernate 3.6.0.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380752/disabling-hibernate-validation-on-save-update-with-hibernate-3-6-0-final)
- [How to disable Hibernate validation in a Spring Boot project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764532/how-to-disable-hibernate-validation-in-a-spring-boot-project)

Comment: Ok but what if really always only want to validate the form, not the database operations but i have to use the same object always? The project im working on right now is really huge and to find all lines in the code where i would have to disable the validation would take very long time. So is there a better way to only validate the form posts using spring?

Comment: You're disabling validation not for each entity but only once, in the hibernate configuration. Or, you have multiple hibernate configurations?